# Is it possible to detect if user tapped on push notification, or launched the app by click on the app icon, when he received push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

Is it possible to detect if user tapped on push notification, or launched the app by click on the app icon?
Let's consider a situation.
The app is inactive. The user got push notification, but he is opening the app, not by notification, but tap on app icon. How detect it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apple's documentation on UISceneDelgate/AppDelegate

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate

Methods such as **applicationDidBecomeActive**, **applicationWillEnterForeground**, etc.

Add a breakpoint in those methods then you can proceed to do as needed.